# Most efficient way to compare arrays of objects in typescript?

Tags: node.js, arrays, typescript

I am receiving an array of order objects from 2 different APIs and I want to compare if both arrays contain the same number of orders and values of these orders are also same. Here is how an order looks like

```
class Order {
 id: number;
 coupon: Coupon;
 customerId: number;
 delivered: boolean;
 orderDate: string;
}
 
output1: Order[];
output2: Order[];
```

How can I compare output1 and output without using nested loops and comparing all fiields one by one.

Note:

I don't want to use lodash.

JSON.stringfy() could be an option but I am afraid it can have sorting problem.

Comment: A sorting problem in the object keys or in the array order? If array, could sort both arrays before calling `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: I think it could be in both of them

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to be looping and comparing... You can write a recursive generic deep compare function that you can reuse, but at the end of the day it's still looping and comparing. I understand that you don't want to use lodash, but can at least take a look at their implementation for... um... inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function that serializes an order as a string (maybe use JSON.stringify or something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stable-stringify), then compares sets of those.

```
function key(o: Order) {
  // Or maybe return JSON.stringify(o);
  return `${o.id}-${o.customerId}-${o.orderDate}`;
}

function sameOrders(a: Order[], b: Order[]) {
  const keys = new Set(a.map(key);
  const aHasB = b.every(order => keys.delete(key(order)));
  return aHasB && keys.size === 0;
}
```